# APIs & Data storage - Microsoft / Server

Tags: ios, api, sharepoint, server

I am creating iOS application that needs to interact with RESTful API (which will be going to make).

The problem is I have no knowledge in the realm and would like to ask for some helps. (I tried to learn this for few days but as I study more, I get so confused...)

1. My company has a server that is running with Windows. What is the process of deploying APIs there and use it as data storage as well.
2. My company has Microsoft 365 license so that I have access to SharePoint. I've read there is SharePoint APIs, so it will be nice to integrate with my app. But more I study about it, I've observed AzureAD. Is it something that I must to have in order to utilize MS SharePoint APIs?

I know it is very broad question but I really appreciate for anyone who provides with helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need Azure AD to interact with the sharepoint api, using the oAuth authentication by registering the app into the Azure AD and giving the Sharepoint Management online permissions that are required for you to do the operations that you want.

Comment: Hmm, thank you very much. You just saved my entire day to be wasted.

Comment: Do you need any more clarity?

Comment: Yes... apparently I can have AzureAD. So if I "register" my app there, I can just use SharePoint API? Or do i have to create another web application to handle this...

Comment: There are basically 2 kind of Azure AD application one is for web application and the other is for native, so in your case you need to select the native.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm on the flow. Thank you for the all helps.